# Перенаправить IP (сайта) на локальный

Tags: ip

Дано: программа - делает запросы на сервер по адресу 80.80.80.80(это пример) 
Нужно: перенаправить эти запросы на локальный адрес 192.168.1.100

---

Программа обращается по IP адресу, а не по доменному имени поэтому сделать по простому через hosts не получается. 
Программа работает на windows, жаль, в линукс справился бы через iptables.
Задача кажется простой но я уже несколько дней пытаюсь придумать и найти решение. Может кто то сталкивался с подобным ? Подойдёт решение через роутер ( если обычный Asus n12 не справится с этой задачей готовы приобрести роутер с os системой mikrotik) 
Так сложилось что разработчика уже и не сыскать а сервер обновляется.

Comment: `route add 80.80.80.80 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.100` ?

Comment: В дополнении к вышестоящему сообщению. Это называется маршрутизация, когда согласно правилам пакеты перенаправляются с одного адреса на другой. Например при использовании роутера бывает нужным пробросить внешний порт 80 на один из локальных компьютеров.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n я попробовал это сделать.  Загрузка IP сайта 80.80.80 происходит через 192.168.1.100. Это хорошо. Но мне нужно чтобы он загрузил страницу например ,,index.htm на адресе 192.168.1.100 вместо 80.80.80.

Comment: @ArchDemon и в чем проблема состоит?